# Excel Web Query: Replace query URL with value from another table

Tags: excel

Currently, the colorful table is using a fixed URL. I want to send a user-defined, complete URL string to this web query, and have it update whenever it's changed.

The large white box is a pulldown list (AN358):

[image]

User can choose a new location:

[image]

Which brings up a new URL (AN362) which points to a different web table (always same format). In my case, the colorful table does not change since it's currently a fixed link.

To the right, I converted the blue cells into a new table called "TableYear1" (AN361):

[image]

In power editor, here is the existing query "Year 1":

[image]

In advanced editor, I tried to replace the web link highlighted here:

[image]

With the underlined value here. I know the syntax/usage is probably wrong...it's just to illustrate what I want to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing the code with this

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableYear1"]}[Content]{0}[URL1])),
```

in your example you pass a string (table name), while you need a reference to that table

Comment: you can record a macro that refreshes just the Year1 table and add a button to press after the selection, the only thing is the workbook has to be macro enabled